# rails_admin with rich issue (Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rich-text-editor, rails-admin

I'm trying to use the Rich editor with rails_admin but it seems it cannot find CKEDITOR which, if I understood correctly, doesn't need to be added as a separate gem.

When I try to add a new Post, it won't load any Rich features and I can see **Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined** in the console log.

I'm using the latest version of rich with Ruby 2.1.1 and Rails 4.1.0:

```
gem 'rich', :git => 'https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich.git'
```

Everything seems properly loaded, I have the Post model added in the rails_admin.rb

```
  config.model Post do
    edit do
      field :title
      field :body, :rich_editor do
        config({
          :insert_many => true
        })
      end
    end
  end
```

When I'm using the 1.4.6 version of the gem, I get a totally different error:

Sprockets::FileNotFound in Devise::Sessions#new
Showing /home/bojan/workspace/nuketest/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

```
couldn't find file 'ckeditor/'
  (in /***/***/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rich-1.4.6/app/assets/javascripts/rich/editor/ckeditor_path.js.erb)
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Changed :rich_editor to :ck_editor and it worked!

```
  config.model Post do
    edit do
      field :title
      field :body, :ck_editor do
        config({
          :insert_many => true
        })
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. I switched to 1.4.7 to use :carrierwave with :ck_editor it throws an options exception. 

    undefined method `config' for #<RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::CKEditor:0x007fe12a337af8>

With 1.4.6 and Paperclip the console said it couldn't find CKEDITOR.
Rails 4.1 w/ Ruby 2

Comment: I am just trying to use rich text editor without rails-admin on rails4.   I get the same error... I tried installing ckeditor but no work.  I've pretty much given up

Comment: Vigrond, what's going on exactly? I have managed to install just ckedtiro with the same configuration and it worked fine. Let me know what happens, maybe I can help. :)